# Remove characters before any special characters c#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove the characters in a string PRIOR to ANY non-alphanumeric characters.  For instance, say you have a name "James Ebanks-Blake", I can split this into an array by using:

```
var s = "James Ebanks-Blake".Split(' ');
```

Even if there are more than one space, it'll just make more array indexes.
So what I need to do is loop thru all the arrays, find indexes with a special character, then remove all the indexes and the special character.

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: What's your expected output of the above? "Blake"? What do you consider a "special" character?

Comment: i only want to get "Blake" in this case.  So special characters would be those that aren't a thru z or any digits.  In this fashion, the same code would work if the person's name was Scarlet O'Hara.  (Which would yield "Hara", and while that may be trivial, there are cases where it would be pertinent...

Comment: So you would expect just "Hara" from the Scarlet example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works here

```
[-^$#](.*)
```

Just add what you consider special characters inside the character class

The string that you want will be in group 1

```
resultString = Regex.Match(subjectString, "[-^$#](.*)", RegexOptions.Singleline).Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: This one seems to work except for when I tried it on the Scarlett O'Hara version.  I doesn't produce any result.  Looks like the regex needs a little tweak.  (I have no idea what's going on in a regex expression).

Comment: Just add what you consider special inside the character class i.e. between [ and ]. So for Scarlett O'Hara you need to add the single quote ' and it becomes  [-^$#']

Comment: Right... I got it now... the "character class" is inside the bracketts... so I added the ' in there and it worked!

Awesome.  Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

`[-'](.*)`

That should grab anything after a `-` and a `'`. If you want, you can add more characters in the [ ] section. Just make sure to escape special regex ones.